# create new line in string on occurrence of word (trivial)

Tags: python

Hello I have a sentence such as:

```
<s>the cat</s><s>sat on a mat</s><s>he wore a hat</s>
```

I want:

```
<s>the cat</s>
<s>sat on a mat</s>
<s>he wore a hat</s>
```

I tried:

```
thisString.split("</s>")
```

this works but it deletes the `</s>` and removes whitespace (i want to keep both)

sorry for the trivial question but I cannot find a solution

Comment: What whitespace does it remove? There's none in the example except between words.

Comment: Why split? Can't you replace `</s><s>` by `</s>\n<s>`?

Comment: Firstly who ever down voted, please link my to a duplicate question I cannot find one... secondly split deletes the whitespace between words I want to keep this white space, thirdly yes this is what I want to do automatically..

Comment: @JoshuaofX: no, split, when given an explicit string to split on, does **not** remove whitespace between words. You are getting confused with the `str.split()` or `str.split(None)` cases, where your string is split on arbitrary whitespace instead, but passing in `</s>` instead *disabled that functionality*.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Okay, but how can I stop split deleting occurances of </s>?

Comment: No, it isn't, because it can't.  See http://ideone.com/BOswZP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.split("</s>")`

Will replace `</s>` and split each occurance into a list.

I believe you would want `.replace()`.

```
line = '<s>the cat</s><s>sat on a mat</s><s>he wore a hat</s>'
line = line.replace('</s>', '</s>\n')
print (line)
```

This will replace each `</s>` with the same tag but a newline at the end.

**The output would be:**

```
<s>the cat</s>
<s>sat on a mat</s>
<s>he wore a hat</s>
```

Comment: thank you, funnily I have used replace in this function already...didnt even think about using it thank you

Comment: @JoshuaofX Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

```
import re
thisString = "<s>the cat</s><s>sat on a mat</s><s>he wore a hat</s>"
thisString = re.sub("</s>", "</s>\n", thisString)
```

Comment: Regex is a bit overkill for this.

Comment: Nah... Regex is always the solution. You want to run a DFS, I think you can actually do it with regex. Anyway, @dyrenex has posted a better solution, so I gave him an upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the `join` syntax of python. Hope this code will help you

```
a = '<s>the cat</s><s>sat on a mat</s><s>he wore a hat</s>'
a = '</s>\n'.join(a.split('</s>'))
print a
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<s>the cat</s>
<s>sat on a mat</s>
<s>he wore a hat</s>
```